# After geting the edittext text bigger it goes below all other views on the layout

Tags: android

I am using a `EditText` to get the message from the user but when the message length increases and the `EditText` goes below other elements on the layout. what should I do prevent it going below those elements? It must be at top of every other element

Tried this in manifest file but dosen't work.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GroupChatActivity"
    android:background="#fff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admin_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="ONLY FACULTY CAN SEND MESSAGE"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_bg"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_layout"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/group_message_text"
            android:layout_width="293dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:hint="Text Goes Here"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/group_chat_content_add_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/attach_file" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_send_message_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/send_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/group_chat_layout"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/admin_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: leave a comment if any query

Answer (score 1):

**First way**

For different Android versions, the best ways is to include these parameters :

```
   android:lines="1"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:singleLine="true"
```

**Second way**

You can disable the enter (new line) key, set the input type to text :

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: It does not give user to see what he has typed at once. So it will not work for me. Thank You for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have dynamic **EditText** You can use `android:maxLines` in Your EditText **XML**

If you want to have some behaviour between your elements You can use **CoordinatorLayout**

So as your EditText need to be on the top of all elements you must use CoordinatorLayout
and your final Code must be changed like below

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context=".GroupChatActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admin_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_bg"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="ONLY FACULTY CAN SEND MESSAGE"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/group_chat_content_add_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/attach_file" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/group_message_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:hint="Text Goes Here"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_send_message_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/send_image"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/group_chat_layout" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/group_chat_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/group_chat_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/group_chat_toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: No it didn't work. The problem still remains as it was earlier. Thank you for the help.